# How to override EFContextProvider to create a read only OData entity

Tags: breeze

So I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track, just need some help implementing this the way I want to. So to accomplish this readonly entity, I know I need to subclass the `EFContextProvider` and override a method. I know I can accomplish this by overriding `SaveChanges`, but I'm wondering if I should override the `Dictionary` property instead, leaving the readonly property out of that `Dictionary`. Will this effect anything? If so, what will it effect?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Sorry, if I'm dense...

Comment: Basically, I want to make sure that one of my Entity Framework entities isn't saved in my application. That's all really. I'll update thought with more info

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out, I have to test a bit first though

Comment: Please post back and let us know the approach you took. :)

Comment: Sure thing, after talking to ward. Kind of want to change some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have client logic that prevents it from attempting to save changes to a "read-only" entity. That leaves guarding the server which should reject any request that attempts to save a "read-only" entity, right?

If so, I would put logic in the `EFContextProvider.beforeSaveEntity` that tests if the entity is savable and throws if it is not. I often make my entities inherit from `ISaveable` (my interface) and throw an exception when I see an entity that is not.

Comment: hmm well in my scenario, I want the entity to be readonly for my breeze OData controller, however I have another endpoint (separate controller) that is not OData and it does except new entities to be saved. Think of this entity as a log that happens on the client, and I want it to be sent back to the server, my app is an internal network dash etc. I have it working now, I'm not convinced it's the best way though. I check for the entity by overriding EFContextProvider.beforeSaveEntity by type checking and return false if found... Starting to think I should separate these into separate projects

Comment: Only you know. I personally pull the EFContextProvider out of the controller and wrap it in a separate component. I can configure there and maybe configure differently for the OData controller than the other controller. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yea, I can think I see what your going for now. Thanks Ward